# Подобие объекта функции на языке C

Tags: c, функции

Я попытался создать подобие объекта функции, которые, например, мы можем увидеть в JS. Код основан на макросах, дабы всё выглядело красивее

```
typedef struct functionCall{
    jmp_buf out;
} functionCall;

functionCall *staticFunctionCall;

typedef struct Function{
    jmp_buf in;
} Function;

#define function(func) \
    malloc(sizeof(Function)); \
    if (setjmp(func -> in)){ \
    functionCall *FUNCTION_CALL = staticFunctionCall;

#define endInit \
    longjmp(FUNCTION_CALL -> out,1); \
    }

#define call(func) \
    staticFunctionCall = malloc(sizeof(functionCall)); \
    if (!setjmp(staticFunctionCall -> out)){ \
        longjmp(func -> in, 1); \
    }
    



void run(Function *f){
    printf("Alert0\n");
    if (1) {
        call(f)
    }
    printf("Alert2\n");
}

int main(){
    int g=1;
    Function *f = function(f){
        printf("Alert1\n");
        g=0;
    } endInit
    run(f);
    printf("Alert3\n");
}
```

Так вот, сразу не пугайтесь моего ужасного кода, ниже я объясню, как все по моей теории работает.
function(func) - это макрос, который создает метку в коде, ссылка на которую находится как раз в структуре Function, которая и принимает вид желанного результата.
Попробуем "вызвать" нашу функцию. Для этого я использую макрос call, который как раз возвращается к той метке. Выполнение возвращается к этому фрагменту кода, однако мне не удается вернутся обратно, откуда как раз и был произведен вызов. По итогу, код ломается, а вывод в консоль оканчивается строкой "Alert1". Я прекрасно понимаю, что подобные проблемы могут возникнуть и в случае, когда инициализация происходила в уже завершенном методе. Однако, не стоит пока в это углубляться. Мне лишь важно знать, как тогда правильно реализовать данную затею

Comment: Ну запустил, посмотрел код. У меня бесконечный цикл `Alert0`,`Alert1`,`Alert2`, ... . Какой порядок должен быть в коде? Понятнее расскажите.

Comment: @AlexGlebe У меня при запуске вышло Alert0 Alert1 Alert2 `Alert0` Segmentation fault (core dumped) как я понимаю последовательность должна была закончится `Alert3` а не снова вызвать функцию возможно в этом дело

Comment: Это все интересно, но может просто на C++ писать? :Р

Comment: Если честно, я до конца не понял, что именно вы хотите сделать (больно уж туманно вы это описываете). Может вы сопрограммы  хотите так реализовать?

Comment: А может все проще и вам нужны [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html). Адрес такой функции можно хранить в переменной и вызывать ее из разных мест (естественно, в зоне активации включающей ее). Или если вам нужно переходить на куски кода в функции и возвращаться назад, то можете посмотреть на [Labels as Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values)

Comment: с помощью `longjmp()` можно прыгнуть только вверх по стеку. прыжок вниз — это дичайший UB, как написано в man'e «Результатом может стать маленький (или  не  очень) хаос.» Реализовывать с помощью него лямбды — довольно дикая затея...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код в вопросе выглядит конечно интересно, но возможно я не до конца понял пользу и цель сохранения контекста (setjmp) и последующего перехода (longjmp). Простейший аналог который я могу предложить выглядит так:

```
void run(void * f){
  printf("1\n");
  void (*func) (void) = f;
  func();
  printf("3\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  void f(){
    printf("2\n");
  }
  printf("0\n");
  run(f);
  printf("4\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Что касается хороших примеров использования вышеуказанных инструкций:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdnoreturn.h>
 
jmp_buf jump_buffer;
 
noreturn void a(int count) 
{
    printf("a(%d) called\n", count);
    longjmp(jump_buffer, count+1); // вернет count + 1 из setjmp
}
 
int main(void)
{
    volatile int count = 0;
    if (setjmp(jump_buffer) != 9)
        a(++count);
}

/* напечатает:
a(1) called
a(2) called
a(3) called
a(4) called
a(5) called
a(6) called
a(7) called
a(8) called
*/
```

[Следующая программа выводит «1 2 3»](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/setjmp):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf ebuf;
void f2 (void);

int main(void){
  char first = 1;
  int i;
  printf("1 ");    
  i = setjmp(ebuf); // <+
  if (first) {      //   | 
    first =! first; //   |  
    f2();   // _________+
    printf ("не будет напечатано");
  }
  printf("%d", i);
  return 0;
}

void f2(void){
  printf("2 ");
  longjmp(ebuf, 3);
}
```

Собственно говоря эти примеры хорошо показывают куда происходит *прыжок*, а именно: туда где вызвана инструкция `setjmp`. По этой причине в коде вопроса и происходит зацикливание.

**Решение задачи:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdnoreturn.h>

typedef struct functionCall{
    jmp_buf out;
} functionCall;

typedef struct Function{
    jmp_buf in;
} Function;

functionCall *staticFunctionCall;

#define function(func) \
    malloc(sizeof(Function)); \
    functionCall *FUNCTION_CALL = staticFunctionCall;  \
    if (setjmp(func -> in)){ \
    printf("func start\n");  


#define endInit(breaker) \
    printf("func end\n");  \
      longjmp(breaker ,1); \
    }

#define call(func) \
    staticFunctionCall = malloc(sizeof(functionCall)); \
    if (setjmp(staticFunctionCall -> out) != 1){ \
        printf("start call\n"); \
        longjmp(func -> in, 2); \
        printf("end call\n"); \
    }

jmp_buf breaker; 
   
void run(Function *f){
  printf("run start\n");
    call(f)
  printf("run end\n");
}

int main(){
  int r; 
  r = setjmp(breaker);
  if (!r){
    Function *f = function(f){
      printf("func body\n");
    } endInit(breaker)
    run(f);
  } 
  printf("end\n");
}
```

результат:

```
run start
start call
func start
func body
func end
end
```

Comment: по задумке OP'а должен был бы ещё и `run end` печататься после `func body`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer `run end` как и `end call` код печатать не может по причине прыжка, тем более я так понимаю это техническая функция которая занимается только запуском функций, так что не думаю что это большая проблема.

Comment: не... ИМХО OP хотел сделать лямбды (функторы, замыкания, «*подобие объекта функции, которые, например, мы можем увидеть в JS*»), так что этот код почти наверняка не то, что он хотел... но `longjmp()` для его задачи в принципе не подходит, иак что тут без особых претензий...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я лишь починил код, тоже без претензий, все ломают голову что нужно было сделать. пусть автор вопроса сам сделает вывод о пользе этого решения.

Comment: Ммм.. То что нужно. Оказывается, это было уже реализовано в языке. По сути, данный способ способен полностью заменить использование лямбда-выражений, которые я и хотел имитировать. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @ЮрийКайдаулов рад что помог